# Pronoun-antecedent agreement question

Tags: pronouns, antecedents

I was reading [this](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2009/11/04/tina-feys-10-favorite-30-rock-moments.html) article about jokes on 30 Rock. A sentence seemed strange to me, and I had to reread a few times. They are talking about a writer, Robert Carlock, writing jokes for a character, Dr. Spaceman:

> Robert Carlock, in particular, is the Spaceman expert. Most of the
>   jokes for him, as this one did, come from him.

So, the antecedents are in the first sentence, and the pronouns are in the second. From the context you can figure out that the first `him` is referring to Spaceman, and the 2nd `him` is referring to Carlock. The sentence just seems very awkward. Is it grammatically correct? Could there be a more clear way to have written it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pronoun-antecedent relationship is studied under the umbrella of **anaphora**.

Wikipedia describes it thusly:

> "In linguistics, anaphora /əˈnæfərə/ is the use of an expression the interpretation of which depends upon another expression in context (its antecedent or postcedent)." - Wikipedia, the Free Encyclopedia

There is always some ambiguity introduced with the presence of two or more antecedents. The sentence is not ungrammatical as such, but it is quite a load on the brain to understand and should be cleared up.

The greatest clarification (keeping the current form) would be achieved by repetition of the antecedent, which is usually awkward. I would have combined the sentences into a more singular thought -- something like this:

> "Robert Carlock, in particular, is the Spaceman expert; as a result, most of Carlock's jokes, like this one, are borrowed from Spaceman."

Hope this helps.

Comment: This has a different meaning from the analysis offered by OP.

Comment: Thanks, @EdwinAshworth. Are you referring to my proposed rewriting of the sentence or my assessment of the devices and grammaticality of the original text? Further, could you explain, so that I am aware of the error?

Comment: 'most of Carlock's jokes, like this one, are borrowed from _Spaceman_.' means that that's where Carlock gets most of his jokes from. But OP interprets 'Most of the jokes for _Spaceman_, as this one d[oes], come from [are written/authored by] Carlock.'